# does not contain definition for "Method"

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

I have a *WCF* application with *SOAP* and *RESTful* end points which I followed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) tutorial.

everything was working great I could call `basicHttpbinding` data. Now I am trying to call data from the `RESTful` side, I received this error when coding the

> Error 1 'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGetAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Method'

the error is shown here:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getTrucksA")]
    List<RTrucks> GetTrucksA();
```

I did check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039839/wcf-cannot-resolve-webget-symbol-what-am-i-doing-wrong) question on Stack Overflow and tried all answers like

- Removing `using System.ServiceModel.Web` and adding it again.
- Adding Reference
- changing the Framework target in my project settings

  but nothing works.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebGet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) as defined by MS does not require the Method = 'Get' as you posted because WebGet is for the verb GET, you can use WebInvoke(Method='POST') for POST.

Comment: yeah dumb mistake I should use WebInvoke. @wjvander Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`WebGetAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a property named `Method`. There is no need to set the method as `WebGet` always refers to a `GET` request. So remove the part `Method = "Get",` and you are good to go.